# Replace Pandas Dataframe Value Based on Index Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas Dataframe named df. I want to replace each value in sentence column within start and end with **X**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['I eat chicken', 'I drive car'], 
                   'start': [3, 3],
                    'end': [6,8]})
```

For example that will return `I X chicken` and `I X car` in sentence column. I try using apply and replace, but it returns error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply, with just the correct function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sentence[:x.start-1] + ' X ' + x.sentence[x.end:], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    I  X chicken
1        I  X car
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `slice_replace`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.slice_replace(start=x['start']-1, stop=x['end']-1, repl='X'),1).sentence
0    I X chicken
1        I X car
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```